# Maven 3: Accessing parent.parent.version from grandchild pom

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom, docker-maven-plugin

I have a problem accessing **parent.parent.version** from grandchild pom.

Here is the exact description of the problem:

Parent pom:

```
<groupId>com.parent</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
.
.
.
<properties>
    <child.version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</child.version>
</properties>
```

Child pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.child</groupId>
<artifactId>child</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>${child.version}</version>
```

GrandChild pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.child</groupId>
    <artifactId>child</artifactId>
    <version>${child.version}</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.grandchild</groupId>
<artifactId>grandchild</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>${project.parent.version}</version>
.
.
.
<profiles>
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
   <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
   <configuration>
      <imageName>artifactory:6001/${project.name}:${parent.parent.version}</imageName>
      <serverId>docker</serverId>
      <dockerDirectory>${project.basedir}</dockerDirectory>
      <resources>
         <resource>
            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
         </resource>
      </resources>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>build</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
</profile>
```

Whenever I build this project, I get below exception:

> Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.0.0:build (default) on project grandchild: Exception caught: The template variable 'parent.parent.version' has no value -> [Help 1]

How do I get parent.parent.version(main project version) from grandchild pom. 
**Docker version should be same as main project version. Thats the goal for me!!!**

Comment: Wouldn't creating a new property at the grandparent level that is initialized to `${project.version}` and use it in the child work?

Comment: Let's say variable _docker.version_ is initialized to ```${project.version}``` in the Parent pom. When maven build starts, it builds grandchild first and that populates _docker.version_ to ```${project.version}```. Here project is the current project which is the grandchild and so the _docker.version_ will be **1.3-SNAPSHOT**.